# PostGIS: DEALLOCATE addfeatures returned 7 [ERROR: prepared statement "addfeatures" does not exist

Tags: qgis, postgis, error, add-feature

I have a connection to a PostGIS database in QGIS and am able to connect and view features successfully, however when trying to add new features I continue to get the following error message:

> WARNING Query: DEALLOCATE addfeatures returned 7 [ERROR: prepared statement "addfeatures" does not exist]

and the COMMIT rolls back. I am however, able to add features with geometry directly using SQL insert statements.

I've tied creating new connections with various options including "Use estimated table metadata" but without success. I've also tried various other QGIS versions including the LTR and latest releases. The error also occurs on other QGIS installation on other computers.

All tables on this particular PostgreSQL database exhibit the same issue, but other databases are unaffected and new features can be added.

I've also updated the PostGIS extension.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] your Question to specify the *exact* releases of PostgreSQL, PostGIS, and QGIS in use.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/6880909ee7f7da686ed699fffb2fff3d03365001/src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp#L2808), we can see that deallocating the prepared statement can occur twice: at the end of the add feature function, just before the commit, and also in the error handling section. So if there is an issue during the commit, the 2nd deallocation attempt will trigger an error.

Since the issue occurs only a specific table, the table is likely the source of the issue. It could be, for example, a deferred constraint that is validated (and fails) at commit time. [Other things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674370/can-committing-an-transaction-in-postgresql-fail) can make a commit fail.